# What kind of neural network should I use to to find the equation of this data set?

Tags: python, matplotlib, neural-network

I am new to the idea of machine learning and neural networks, but I find myself with a problem that I think a neural network could solve (given my basic understanding) and I’m really hoping you could give me a point in the right direction.

I have a set of data that was acquired through physical testing, consisting of 2 independent variables (airspeed and pitch) and a dependent variable (power).  I’m wondering if a neural network can help me generate a formula to generalize this into a function [f(airspeed, pitch)=power] that I could graph and plot using python!

Here is the data I gathered from my testing plotted in 3d:

[image: Plotted Data]

Is a neural network the right tool to do this?  Can you point me in a direction to study?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is too broad to be answered. Looking at the plot you simply need some interpolation technique.

Comment: If you are trying to find an equation, likely, you want some curve-fitting approach, either a parametric one (perhaps you have some theoretical idea about the nature of the curve) or a non-parametric one.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Is there some more information I could provide to narrow my question?  I gathered the data by steadily increasing the airspeed while the pitch remained static, while continually monitoring the power output.  Then, I increased the pitch and did the same.  What I am hoping to learn through the use of this neural network is what would happen as the pitch changes continuously as I am unable to reliably vary the pitch in a controlled way at the moment.  I am hoping to be able to turn this scatter plot into a smooth surface that represents the physical experiment.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : or am I asking the wrong question all together?  In most of the examples I've seen so far of neural networks, the network is used for classification... but, I would like to use a neural network to output a continuous real value.  Am I just trying to apply a neural network where none is needed?

Comment: I'm not saying that you cannot use a neural network. What I'm saying is that I wouldn't know why and how to use one in this case. The experiment you describe seems pretty standard (observing one quantity as two others change). So the usual approach is either interpolation of the data or curve fitting (if some physical law should be verified).  Remeber that this site is about programming, so you may choose one approach and ask a question about the problems you have implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try K-means clustering algorithm? This might help.

https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/clustering-with-k-means-in-python/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, maybe you could help me understand something better though; the output (target?) of my function should be (mostly) continuous.  Clustering with k-means seems to label things into groups.  Since the output of the function is power in Watts, would this fall under something that could be determined with k-means?  I'm sorry if I'm missing something, just eager to learn!

Comment: Ah, maybe i didnt read your post correctly. You're right in regards to K-means labels data into groups, which causes a cluster. Which is something you do not want. Id have to look around, there is an algorithm for it though i read about the other day. Apologies. If i remember ill get back to you, happy hunting and happy programming!

Comment: Thanks!  I've got a prototype running the MLPClassifier from sklearn... but I'm having some trouble understanding the output since I'm not really sure what I'm doing yet haha

Comment: Haha, do any of us have any idea what we are doing when we first start? "Let me just click run" "hm nope" *fixes a couple things "still nope"